# Magento Filter orders by state

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to do exporting orders from magento store

```
    $myOrder=Mage::getModel('sales/order'); 
    $orders=Mage::getModel('sales/mysql4_order_collection');
    $allIds=$orders->getAllIds();
```

But it  returns all orders to me.

How can i filter orders by state "new"?

I'm trying

`$orders->addFieldToFilter('state',Array('eq'=>"new"));` or
`$myOrder->setData('state','new');`

but magento still returns all orders.

Comment: You should better try here http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this

```
$order= Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('state', 'new');
$allIds = $order->getAllIds();
```

or  you can use

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect("*")->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'status', 'eq'=>'pending')));
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to clarify more detail. But, that will help to you.

```
echo "$order->getSelect()->addFieldToFilter('state',Array('eq'=>"new"))->__toString();
```

this script will print to like that "`Select * from your_table where state='new'`";
Then copy result and go to phpmyadmin or workbench. run this query.
Result query will show you right or not.
Hope this help